# How to get all names of checked checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

At the end of my HTML site I want to show the name of all checked checkboxes.

For example, if I have following checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Product1" value="149"  id="checkbox_1" autocomplete="off"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Product2" value="249"  id="checkbox_2" autocomplete="off"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Product3" value="349"  id="checkbox_3" autocomplete="off"/>
```

The name of all the ones who are checked, should be listed on any position on the same page without pressing a button.

Like this, if he choosed 2 and 3:

```
You choosed following products:
Product2
Product3
```

If he choosed nothing, nothing should appear.

Answer (score 2):

```
var names = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function(){ return this.name; });
if (names.length) {
    console.log(names.get().join(','));
}
```

It would be better if they had a shared class though, then you could make the selector better with

```
$('.theclass').filter(':checked').map(function(){ return this.name; });
```

```js
//demo example
$(function(){
  //get all the products
  var $allProducts = $('.product');
  //get the area to write the results to
  var $selectedProductsListing = $('#selectedProducts');
  //get the label
  var $selectedProductsLabel = $('#selectedProductsLabel');
  
  //when you click a checkbox, do the logic
  $allProducts.on('click', function(){
    //set the content of the results
    $selectedProductsListing.html(
      //only return those that are checked
      $allProducts.filter(':checked').map(function(index, checkbox){
        //return a div string with the name for display
        return '<div>'+ checkbox.name +'</div>';
      }).get().join('') //get the array of strings and join them by nothing
    );
    
    //hide the label if no checkboxes are selected
    if ($selectedProductsListing.text().trim().length) {
      $selectedProductsLabel.show();
    } else {
      $selectedProductsLabel.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="Product1" value="149" class="product" id="checkbox_1" autocomplete="off"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Product2" value="249" class="product" id="checkbox_2" autocomplete="off"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Product3" value="349" class="product" id="checkbox_3" autocomplete="off"/>

<div id="selectedProductsLabel" style="display:none">Products Selected:</div>
<span id="selectedProducts"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you! How I print the result?

Comment: Updated with a console log. @Chris

Comment: If I use: document.write(names); 

then I get [object Object]

Comment: Right, because names is a jQuery object.  If you look at my console.log you will see I am performing a `get()` to get the array of strings, and then I am `join(',')` them into a single string to print.

Comment: ok but then how can I implement it in my code without pressing a button? Can you give me an example maybe? :/ Thank you!

Comment: None of the logic in my answer has anything to do with pressing a button.  It's up to you when to run the logic.

Comment: ok, but how I "run" it in the html code? How I implement the jQuery object?

Comment: @Chris added demo to the answer as an example.

Comment: One last question... How I hide the div "Products selected"? I already tried by adding the line "<script>$('.showcase-caption span:empty').parent().hide();</script>" and added class to the div but it doesn't work...

Comment: @Chris updated demo to only show the label if one or more checkboxes are checked.

Comment: Works perfekt! Really appreciate it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you could check below snippet:

```js
$("input").click(function(){
  var seList = $("input:checked").map(function(v){
    return (this.name);
  })
  $("#info").html(seList.join("<br>"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="Product1" value="149"  id="checkbox_1" autocomplete="off"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Product2" value="249"  id="checkbox_2" autocomplete="off"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Product3" value="349"  id="checkbox_3" autocomplete="off"/>
<div id="info">
</div>
```